# How could I set color for different letters?

Tags: python, bash, colors

In bash terminal:

```
cat AGTC.txt
AGCTGGCCAGGTGCCCAGGTCCCC
```

This is basically four DNA nucleotides. How could I color each of them,
say A colored as Green; 
    G colored as Brown; 
    C colored as Blue; 
    T colored as Red

In bash or Python, how could we do that?

tHX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `echo` command like this with `eval` (*`-e` flag*) (with bash colors):

```
# Set all Bash color vars
A_COLOR="\e[32mA"
G_COLOR="\e[33mG"
C_COLOR="\e[34mC"
T_COLOR="\e[31mT"
NO_COL="\e[0m"

# Set DNA, and perform colored replacements
DNA="AGCTGGCCAGGTGCCCAGGTCCCC"
DNA=${DNA//A/${A_COLOR}}
DNA=${DNA//G/${G_COLOR}}
DNA=${DNA//C/${C_COLOR}}
DNA=${DNA//T/${T_COLOR}}$NO_COL

# Print DNA!
echo -e $DNA
```

Color [reference for bash](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

Comment: Thanks! Looks simple. But I run your code and get \[\]A\[\]\[\]G\[\]\[\]C\[\]\[\]T\[\]\[\]G\[\]....How could I remove those slash and parenthesis?

Comment: Just fixed it @wang

Answer (score 1):

You can use a python library called [termcolor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor).
With it you can set the output text of strings with colors. like this:

```
from termcolor import colored
print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

the output of this in terminal would be the word "hello" in red text and the work "world" in green text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to colorize output using BASH, check out the color codes and replace letters appropriately

http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

```
A --> [92mA
G --> [33mG
C --> [34mC
T --> [31mT
```

With Python (running under BASH), you could use the same syntax as above to produce color in your terminal.

```
echo -e "\e[92mA\e[33mG\e[34mC\e[31mT\e[33mG\e[33mG\e[34mC\e[34mC\e[92mA\e[33mG\e[33mG\e[31mT\e[33mG\e[34mC\e[34mC\e[34mC\e[92mA\e[33mG\e[33mG\e[31mT\e[34mC\e[34mC\e[34mC\e[34mC"
```

The above echo produces the right output in BASH